# print.less file error when run deploy command

Tags: magento2, configuration, deploy, core-file-storage

[image]

When running php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy command it shows above error, I just replace the magento 2.1.6 files to magento 2.1.0 files now theme working fine but when run deploy command it shows the error.Please help somebody..

Answer (score 0):

Show me all file print.less, please.

Variable **@media-common** set in **/lib/web/css/source/lib/_responsive.less**

May be your theme override this core file and it no contains the variable? Check file in this path:

> /app/design/frontend/Novaworks/thebear/web/css/source/lib/_responsive.less

Also try to reset the cache in **/var/view_preprocessed** and try again.

> rm -rf var/view_preprocessed && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: the error shows again when try to clear view_preprocessed file then run deploy command

Comment: Do you may show your print.less? I think that together we will find the reason of problem.

Comment: http://urbanzaveri.com/pub/static/frontend/Novaworks/thebear/en_US/css/print.less

Comment: This is the print.less file link

Comment: I have 404 error, not found

Comment: I just click this link file is downloaded

Comment: @import 'source/_theme.less'; // Theme overrides

Comment: It is in print.less files may be this is the problem right?

Comment: Still I don't know. Your theme inherit from magento/blank? print.less same in core standard theme. Lets see _theme.less and _variables.less, more to look for a mistake nowhere

Comment: Your theme override this less files (_theme.less and _variables.less)?

Comment: how to solve my problem

Comment: Show me your _theme.less and _variables.less. Otherwise, I can not help you

Comment: I downloaded those files how to share

Comment: https://pastebin.com?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/WxyuAHwf

Comment: _theme.less - https://pastebin.com/FM4YteeQ

Comment: Ok, file components/_modals.less included in _theme.less. I think it should not be there. Try just comment this line: @import 'components/_modals.less';

Comment: Not working it shows same error again

Comment: What kind of error? In file _modals.less? Screen me, please

Comment: No forget clean /var/view_preprocessed before static deploy

Comment: frontend/Novaworks/thebear/en_US/nova/font-awesome/less/rotated-flipped.less
  variable @fa-css-prefix is undefined in file /home/auzmind/public_html/var/
 view_preprocessed/css/frontend/Novaworks/thebear/en_US/nova/font-awesome/le
  ss/rotated-flipped.less in rotated-flipped.less on line 4, column 2
  2| // ------------------------
  4| .@{fa-css-prefix}-rotate-90  { .fa-icon-rotate(90deg, 1);  }
  5| .@{fa-css-prefix}-rotate-180 { .fa-icon-rotate(180deg, 2); }
  6| .@{fa-css-prefix}-rotate-270 { .fa-icon-rotate(270deg, 3); }
  7|

Comment: The error in rotated-flipped.less file

Comment: Unfortunately, it is very difficult to understand without seeing the whole picture. I'm ready to solve the problem if you give access to files

Comment: can i connect team viewer or anydesk do you have?

Comment: Yes, I can work with team viewer

Comment: Id : 767 977 171   Password :  6453

Comment: do you connect?